Data lifecycle policy for Amazon Open Search Service: 24-hours data deletion
Collection Name : AOS
Index Name : Error-log
How can I configure OpenSearch to automatically delete data from an index after one day?
We generated one data lifecycle policy using the following query, however it is not working.
"Resource": [
"index/aos/error-logs"
],
"ResourceType": "index",
"MinIndexRetention": "24h"
}

I faced the same problem. It is not deleting the documents after a day.
